# Auto-layout constraints to make WKWebView go full screen

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, wkwebview

I will mention right away that I'm not iOS developer and this is first time I'm messing with it because I was asked to update web application inside iOS WKWebView wrapper.

I managed to load the web app inside iOS app but on iPhone X there is always white space on top and bottom. I just learned about constraints and I heard that this is default safe area behaviour. I'm trying to expand my WKWebView past safe area to go all the way to the top notch and bottom home button so that there are no white spaces. Inside Xcode all constraints for safe area object is set equal to superview, following web view container object set equal to superview. But I still have white spaces on top and bottom.

There is also top "View" object which I think is elsewhere known as superview, which when I click on I see the constraints for it set equal to safe area and I can only keep it set to safe area or web view container which itself is set to superview. I find this very confusing. What am I doing wrong here?

I would appreciate help regarding storyboard and not code related as I don't speak Swift.

EDIT: Snapshots of constraints

Web View Container Object: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQP15.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you use storyboard, you can do like this:

1. select this constraint and at the right panel, you should change the `Second item` form `Safe Area` to `SuperView` like below:

[image]

[image]

2. modify the Constant value from `44` to `0`, like below:

[image]

3. the same operation to other constraints.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate a quick answer. This is my exact constraints right now. And so for all of them (first item web view being set to second item superview with Constant values at 0). Is Superview is the same as View? Beause my top level View object is equal to safe area and can't be changed.

Comment: can you post your snapshot about your storyboard?

Comment: Sorry，You provide too many constraints and I can't see the layout about the storyboard, so I can't figure out what problem is.

Comment: Sorry about that. I removed all the constraints and have only these 5 for webview. The top is already going past safe area all the way to the top. But the bottom now has even bigger white gap. I tried everything. HTML has viewport-fit: cover. https://imgur.com/GcRFeL0
Webview object has a height of 832px and width of 375px. Is that okay? All constraints are set to 0.

Comment: Fixed it by clicking and dragging WebView to View object and selecting WebView to use View's height. So it must've been height/width problem. I had some random height and width on Web View object but I ignored it as I thought it's going to adapt to any screen size by using 0 value constraints anyway. Confused.